# OS X Terminal Cursor Problem

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, terminal

This morning I bumped into something I've never seen before and I can't seem to find a way to fix it. I was inspecting a *large* bzipped tarball (e.g. `tar jtf myfile.tar.bz2`) and before it completed, I hit `Ctrl+C` to abort the output since I'd seen as much as I needed to see. The output stopped and the prompt appeared.

So far, nothing out of the ordinary, but then I tried to type. And nothing appeared. And the cursor didn't move. Or blink. What I typed did *register*, though. Although there's no visible indication that I had done anything, the command I typed executed when I pressed `Enter`. The `Enter` key *does* work.

Has anyone ever seen this? Any idea how I can get back to zero without having to quit and relaunch terminal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It happens sometime that the shell gets all messed up.
I found that sending a reset give me back my prompt.

I found 2 ways to do that:

- Using the mouse to select Shell > Send Reset (command-R)
- Or typing `reset` in the terminal

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'd love to know _why_ the shell gets messed up, but this really did help. I can reproduce the issue at will, but as soon as I type `reset` (even though I can't see it) and hit `Enter`...poof! Good as new. Thank you.

Comment: In MacOS El Capitan's *Terminal*, it's `Shell -> Reset (Alt+Cmd+R)` or (if needed, ) `Hard Reset (Ctrl+Alt+Cmd+R)`.
In *iTerm2*, it's `Session -> Reset (Cmd+R)`.

Comment: @RobWilkerson this keeps happening to me when pytest (Python test framework) crashes.